# One large Elasticsearch lookup index, or several smaller ones?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, information-retrieval

I'm creating a lookup index that I'll use solely as a [terms filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-terms-query.html). So no searching/aggregating, only filtering and `GET`s.

I'm debating the structure of this lookup index, whether each document should contain *all* of the fields I want to filter for, or whether I should create an index per field.

For example, let's say each document pertains to a user. Each user has a list of games they've played, books they've read, and movies they've watched. When searching for game/book/movie recommendations, I'll use the term filter to filter out those items they've already interacted with.

I'm wondering if I should have a single lookup index with a document mapping like:
`users_index`

```
{
  'game_ids': [],
  'movie_ids' : [],
  'book_ids': []
}
```

or one index *per* lookup value, like:
`user_games_index`

```
{
  'game_ids': []
}
```

`user_movies_index`

```
{
  'movie_ids': []
}
```

`user_books_index`

```
{
  'book_ids': []
}
```

Pros for one index:

1. Each index comes with overhead, so the fewer the better
2. If I ever want to retrieve *all* of a user's info, it's all in one index

Pros for multiple indices:

1. According to the [update api docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html), updating a document means retrieving the whole thing first. I will be updating each document a lot, and those arrays can become rather large (think thousands of ids). Updating a book id will then retrieve all of the game ids, which takes up memory. If they were in separate indices, I could avoid that.
2. Just easier to maintain on my end of things

I should note that if I use multiple indices, it'll only be 4 or 5, with about 500k documents per index. Also, only 1 primary shard per index, no replicas, and I'm on a single m5.2xlarge EC2 instance (8 cores, 32G ram).

Are these stats so small that it won't really matter at this point, or should I favor one index or many?

Answer (score 0):

How about a third option?

You have one index and each of your document in the index looks something like this:

```
{
    "user_id" : "some_user",
    "document_type" : "movie" or "game" or "book"
    "document_id" : "id of movie, game or book"
}
```

Why? Since you say a user's games, movies or books will be updated often, this approach lets you easily add / delete individual movies, games or books for users.

You also can easily filter the books/movies/games for specific users.

All values are of type "keyword" and filtering should be fast.

PS: A "good" mapping for an ES index will try to minimize the numbers of updates on individual documents and rather work at the level of inserting / deleting documents as ES does this task very well compared to finding & updating documents.

Edit: I have added query examples to illustrate how you can filter out results with bool query.

Example:

1. I want all movies / games / books a user X has NOT interacted with.

GET _search

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not":{
        "term" : {
            "user_id" : "user X"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. I want only movies a user X has NOT interacted with.

GET _search

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not":{
        "term" : {
            "user_id" : "user X"
        }
      },
      "filter":{
        "term" : {
            "document_type" : "movie"
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a really good idea, but how would I filter out _all_ of a user's movies/books/games in a single query?

Comment: It is possible with the Boolean Query. More information here:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: I have updated the example queries of filtering out a users interactions

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. The problem with this is that the user info index is different from the index that holds all the item recommendations. 

So I need to do a terms lookup filter (as shown in [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/query-dsl-terms-query.html))